# Alternative to Security tags

Tags: spring-boot

I'm attempting to port over a huge website to Spring Boot. I have just about every piece of put in place except the security in JSP.
Unfortunately, the library that supports the security tag lib;

Causes my project to crash. I've tried looking for conflicts in the pom file but it's not to be.

I was able to get the principle using scriptlets but there are several times I conditionally display menus, based upon the authorization of the user. I even thought of writing my own tag libs but I it would take too long.

Are there any security tag libs that specifically work with Spring-Boot?

Comment: Maybe provide an example - but there are spring-sec tags - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html

Comment: "Causes my project to crash" <-- That's a real problem that I would solve if I were you.

Comment: Update; I ended up writing my own tag libs to replace what was lost when the spring tag lib wouldn't load. I only needed a few tags (i.e. get principal, is Authorized, is is not Authorized and has authorizations).